# AMP Loading Div Blocking Brightcove Video

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html, brightcove

In my AMP page, I have a few Brightcove videos in a carousel. After scrolling the carousel such that any videos are off screen and then scrolling back, there is a loading spinner that blocks the video indefinitely.
All of the API requests are coming back with 200. In fact, it's just a loading div (class "i-amphtml-loading-container i-amphtml-fill-content"). If I hide the div or even click on it, the video plays fine.

Anyone know why that loading spinner keeps going and how to stop it? I wanna say its part of the amp-brightcove component. This issue *does not* occur when the page is initially loaded -- only after videos go off screen.

```
  <amp-carousel
    class="some-class"
    type="carousel"
    layout="fixed-height"
    height="150"
  >
    <div>
      <amp-brightcove
        class="brightcove-video"
        data-account="account-id"
        data-video-id="video-id"
        data-player="player-id"
        data-embed="default"
        data-param-tracking-data="{key: val}"
        data-param-custom-ad-data="something"
        layout="fixed"
        width="160"
        height="90"
      >
    </amp-brightcove>
    <div class="video-title">Some title</div>
   </div>
  </amp-carousel>
```

Comment: Can you link to the code ?

Comment: @StefanyNewman yup, just added some code